# How to implement a DFA which recognizes comments?

Tags: java, dfa

I'd need some help with Java here...
I have to implement a DFA in Java that recognizes Java comments contained between `/*` and `*/`. 
In order to start with simple things, let's say that DFA's alphabet is: `{'/', '*', 'a'}`, so it recognizes only those 3 elements.
Possible accepted Strings:

1) `/**/`

2) `/****/`
3) `/*a*a**/`
4) `/*a**/`

It won't accept:

1) `/*/`

2) `/**/***/`

In order to achieve that I developed this method:

```
    public static boolean scan(String s){
    int i = 0, state = 0;
    while(i < s.length() && stato >= 0){
        final char ch = s.charAt(i++);
        switch(state){
            case 0:
                if(ch == '/')
                    state = 1;
                else 
                    state = -1;
                break;
            case 1: 
                if(ch == '*')
                    state = 2;
                else 
                    state = -1;
                break;
            case 2: 
                if(ch == 'a')
                    state = 2;
                else if(ch == '/')
                    state = 3;
                else 
                    state = -1;
                break;
            case 3: 
                if(ch == '*')
                    state = 4;
                else 
                    state = -1;
                break;
            case 4:
                if(ch == ' ')
                    state = 4;
                else
                    state = -1;
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("State: " + state);
    return state == 4;
}
```

But with simplest input `/**/` `status` variable is `-1`, when it should be `4`.
Which changes should I make?
Hope you guys can help me...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Step 3 your state became -1. then how you get matching.
See this block:

```
case 2: 
            if(ch == 'a')
                state = 2;
            else if(ch == '/')
                state = 3;
            else 
                state = -1;
            break;
```

1. `State 0`  : `char /`  : `nextState 1`
2. `State 1`  : `char *`  : `nextState 2`
3. `State 2`  : `char *`  : `nextState -1`
4. `State -1` : `char /`  : `nextState -1`